# Create vector of form [101, 1001, 10001, ...]

Tags: matlab, vector

I want to create a vector with 7 elements which has the form

```
[101, 1001, 10001, ...]
```

I can't figure out how to do this only using `a:d:b` and `linspace`, without manually inputting the values.

I can't determine the mathematical pattern, just that obviously there is an additional 0 in between each number.

So how would I generate this vector without the use of loops and only the use of `a:d:b` or `linspace`?

Comment: Please stop asking very simple "how to I generate this vector" questions *without any sign of effort*. This is now your fourth in 2 days! It's really appreciated here if you show some existing code or thinking, what you've tried, why it's not right... If you ask a well formed question you will likely get more detailed and informative answer, which will guide your learning and mean you need less help in future. Otherwise it just feels like we're doing your homework for you. Feel free to ask simple questions, but show you've tried to tackle it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your series is actually one added to the powers of 10 and hence:

```
req = 1 + 10.^[2:n+1];   %where n is the total length
```